# Unity3d Use top level variable in class

Tags: function, class, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a problem with using a variable that I declared outside the class, in a class. If I try this, Unity acts as if the variable doesn't exist.

```
#pragma strict
var chunkWidth=49;
class Chunk{
    var width:short;
    var position:Vector3;
    function Chunk(pos:Vector3){
        this.width=chunkWidth; //this gives the error: Unknown identifier: 'chunkWidth'.
        this.position=pos;
    }
}
```

This error also occurs when I want to use a function within the class.

Comment: Do you want to use this as a constant? Or why is it placed outside of a class?

Comment: I use it out of the class so I can slide the width within Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change a variable in the inspector view if the variable is made public. Put the variable inside the class and make it a public variable. Then go to Unity and click the object that has this component attached. You can then change the variable in before you hit play. The variable will save in unity, but not in your code. So if you use this code with another object the variable will need to be set again in the inspector. But once set Unity will save that value within your project.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to make the class extend MonoBehaviour, and for some reason, the position was displayed as well, but the width not. Now I made them private, but I wonder why the position would be displayed but the width wouldn't. I know that variables normally are displayed in the inspector when they aren't made private, but this one isn't...

Comment: If you make a new script in the unity window instead of on your own. It should automatically put the mono develop stuff in there. Only public global variables are displayed in the inspector.